# Inject JavaScript file in a WebView on Android

Tags: javascript, android, webview, inject

I have a function JavaScript that i want to inject in a Html, with the WebView. I can inject small pieces of JavaScript code with loadUrl("javascript:..." but when i try to insert the code does not work.

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var i = 0;

    function timer() {
        tot = document.links.length;
        if (i < tot+1) {
        document.getElementById('link'+i).focus();
            i++;
            setTimeout("timer()", 1000);
        }
    if(i==tot)
        i=0;
    }
    setTimeout("timer()", 1000);

</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its actually simple, once your webview loading is finshed `onPageFinished()` , call `webview.loadUrl(“javascript:your-javascriptcode-here”)` 
take a look [here](http://lexandera.com/2009/01/injecting-javascript-into-a-webview/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
loadUrl("javascript:(function(){" +
  "var i = 0;" +
  "function timer() {" +
  "    tot = document.links.length;" +
  "    if (i < tot+1) {" +
  "    document.getElementById('link'+i).focus();" +
  "        i++;" +
  "        setTimeout('timer()', 1000);" +
  "    }" +
  "if(i==tot)" +
  "    i=0;" +
  "}" +
  "setTimeout('timer()', 1000);" +
"})()");
```